# Regular expression with "not" doesn't work

Tags: javascript, regex

I'd like to create a regular expression to not match some words...

My chars : `var test = "é123rr;and;ià456;or;456543"`

My regular expression : `test.match(\((?!and)(?!or)[A-Za-z0-9àèìòùÀÈÌÒÙáéíóúýÁÉÍÓÚÝâêîôûÂÊÎÔÛãñõÃÑÕäëïöüÿÄËÏÖÜŸçÇßØøÅåÆæœ]+)$\g)`

What I'd like to get from the `match` function (Javascript) : `['é123rr', 'ià456', '456543']`

My result : `['456543']`

Comment: So `split()` on `;and;` and `;or;`.

Comment: Really, split with `;` and filter out values that are equal to `or` and `and` (`test.split(";").filter(x => x!=="or" && x!=="and")`). Or use the known approach: match what you do not need and [match and capture what you need](https://regex101.com/r/xZAw0R/1).

Comment: It would make sense to use `String.prototype.split()` with `;` as a separator...

Comment: I'd like to use regexs and not the `split()` function.

Comment: Why use an MOAB when a pair of scissors does the work perfectly?

Comment: Ok so if it is the best way I'll use the `split()` function.

Comment: If you explained your actual requirements, you would get fewer comments and an appropriate answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can actually split this using regex:

```
test.split(/\;and\;|\;or\;/g); //will return ['é123rr', 'ià456', '456543']
```

If the "and" and the "or" also can appear at the beginning or the ending of the string you can do this:

```
test.split(/\;?and\;?|\;?or\;?/g).filter(str => str != "")
```

This way you clean the empty strings of your array if the above case occur.

Comment: why does split cause an empty string in the array when at the start of a sting ?

Comment: Because when looking into a "and;abcd;or", it will let the non-matched group before/after it untouched and the matched part will be removed. But the non-matched term before/after it is exactly the lambda, the empty string character ""  

For instance:  
"abc;and;def" -> ["abc", "def"] . 
"and;abc;or" -> ["", "abc", ""] .